# how to create Christmas tree in python with layer and base

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanna create a Christmas tree in python with layer and base no random just print Christmas
For example, if I enter the number 3 the program should print:
I wanna output like this

```
       *
      ***
       *
      ***
     *****
       *
      ***
     *****
    *******
       |
    ===V===
```

Code:

```
 a = int(input(''))
for i in range(a, 0, -1):
   for j in range(0, 5):
       print(end=' ')
   for f in range(0, i):
       print(end=' ')
   for h in range(0, 2 * (a - i) + 1):
       print('*', end='')
print()
b = a + 1
for i in range(b, 0, -1):
   for j in range(0, 2):
       print(end=' ')
   for f in range(0, i):
       print(end=' ')
   for h in range(0, (2 * (b - i) + 1)):
       print('*', end='')
print()
c = a + 2
for i in range(c, 0, -1):
   for j in range(0, 1):
       print(end=' ')
   for f in range(0, i):
       print(end=' ')
   for h in range(0, (2 * (c - i) + 1)):
       print('*', end='')
print()
d = a + 3
for i in range(d, 0, -1):
   for f in range(0, i):
       print(end=' ')
   for h in range(0, (2 * (d - i) + 1)):
       print('*', end='')
print()
```

It does not work because when I ran this code program print like this

```
             *
            ***
           *****
           *
          ***
         *****
        *******
           *
          ***
         *****
        *******
       *********
           *
          ***
         *****
        *******
       *********
      ***********
```

I don't know why can you guy help me?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMtMB.png

Comment: _I don't know why can you guy help me?_ Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
n = int(input())
addSpace = 4
for i in range(1, n+1):
    left = " "*(n-i+addSpace)
    for j in range(i+1):
        print(left+" "*(i-j)+"*"*(2*j+1))
print(" "*(n+addSpace) + "|")
print(" "*addSpace + "="*n + "V" + "="*n)
```